# create function sql server 2005 disable errors

Tags: sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a *.bat file which runs all sql-scripts in given folder (every file in this folder has a create function script):

```
for /r "%~dp0\Production\Functions" %%X in (*.sql) do ( 
   sqlcmd -S%1 -d%2 -b -i "%%X"
)
```

But some functions in the folder are depended on others. So I get `Invalid object name` error. Is there a way to disable this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your files so that they're listed in the correct order of precedence. So, for example, if `FuncA.sql` uses `FuncB.sql`, then rename the files as `001-FuncB.sql`, `002-FuncA.sql`.

Comment: This might help, but I'm looking for more "correct" solution if there's one. Thank you for answer.

Comment: You think ignoring/disabling errors is more "correct" than getting the order of precedence and object dependencies right?

Comment: It's much more convenient. Imagine that I have 100 of scripts and I need to add one more with number 10. I have to rename 90 files. That's awful.

Comment: Simply leave some gaps in your numbering system. `0100-FuncB.sql`, `0200-FuncA.sql`, then you could add a `0150-FuncC.sql` when the situation occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to disable errors generated by SQL when you run (what I think of as) code-based object: stored procedures, functions, views, triggers, and anything else that has to be the sole object of a batch submitted to SQL.

It is also awkward at best to work around this problem. Some options:

- One way, as Joe Stefanelli recommends, is to name your files such that they get executed in proper order (by name, or perhaps by date created or something more esoteric).
- Another way is to group *related* functions in single scripts, such that referenced objects must be created before referencing objects.
- Or combine the above two, putting all your dependent objects in one script you can guarantee will always run first. Not so useful if your have nested references.
- A last (and more kludgy) way is to iterate over your scripts several times (assuming your "create" script will properly deal with an object that already exists), until a given pass raises no errors.

For development purposes, we store code-based objects in individual files, but when it comes time to wrap the code up for push to Production systems, I glom the files together, test it, and shuffle the contents around and retest until no more errors are generated.